# Print images when taking print out from chrome/firefox

Tags: asp.net, browser, printing

I am printing one page from my web application from different browser. It contains some small images like tick mark, question mark on page.

Now my problem is that it is not printing images on print out. in IE it works fine and print images but in Google Chrome, Firefox it is not printing images.

Can any one have an idea what to do to print images in print out from Chrome and Firefox?

Thanks in advance.

below is my code for generating image in page.

I am preparing cell with class called 'tickmark'.

```
 HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                        tc.InnerText = "";

                        if (Convert.ToInt64(result[h]) == 1)
                        {
                            tc.InnerHtml = "<b class='tickmark'></b>";
                        }

                        trContent.Cells.Add(tc);
```

and tickmark class having code:

```
b.tickmark { background:url(../images/tickmark.png) no-repeat; width:13px; height:10px; display:block; vertical-align:middle; margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: Show us the code/markup you are using to create these images.

Comment: i have edited my post and add code to generate image in page. can you please look at this and suggest me any thing from in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers do not print background images. These CSS images are meant for styling.

If that image is important, have it embeded on your page. images in a `<img/>` tag will work.

To avoid breaking your current layout, you can do this:

Have another css file print.css and link it as follows:

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="print stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
<div class="tick"><img src="images/tickmark.png" alt="tick" /></div>
```

main.css

```
.tick img {
    display: none;
}
```

print.css

```
.tick img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I already done in my code display: block then also it will not print images.

Comment: The trick is having an `<img/>` tag, that is what gets printed. I am only hiding it in your main css.

Comment: i am new at web application. so can you please tell me how to do coding for the same.

Comment: What part of my answer have you not understood?

Comment: i dont know where to write code. I need to write in tc.InnerHtml = "<b class='tickmark'></b>" line and change the code?

Comment: `tc.InnerHtml = "<b class='tickmark'></b><img src="images/tickmark.png" alt="tick" />"` . Maybe you can just replace your orignial by `tc.InnerHtml = "<img src="images/tickmark.png" alt="tick" />"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14558/discussion-between-brijesh-patel-and-nunespascal)